# A stimulating affix riddle

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

> My prefix indicates friendship
> My infix can be turned another way
> My suffix is one half of an exchange
> **What am I?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are:

> **COFFEE**

*My prefix indicates friendship*

> **CO** is a prefix meaning 'with' or 'mutual', usually representing something two people (for example) might share in a *friendly* way: think 'co-operate', 'co-pilot', 'co-exist', etc.

*My infix can be turned another way*

> Something that is **OFF** can also be *turned another way*: on!

*My suffix is one half of an exchange*

> A **FEE** is something which one person in *an exchange* (like a trade or a sale) will pay in order to receive a commodity in return.

As for the title:

> COFFEE! COFFEE! COFFEE! COFFEE! COFFEE! Er... I mean, coffee is a stimulant, since it contains caffeine.

Answer (score 10):

My answer

> Tightroping

My prefix indicates friendship

> **Tight** is an adjective used to describe a close personal relationship

My infix can be turned another way

> **Ro** which, when turned, gives "or" (another way)

My suffix is one half of an exchange

> **Ping** which is a query in computing to determine whether there is a connection or not (the affirmative reply being "pong")

Title

> Tightroping (synonym for tightrope walking) is indeed a stimulating activity.

Comment: Not the right answer, but that was pretty funny!